# Angular on change event for select menu

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sorting

Using Angular I have a dataset which is called via $http.get, filtered and then displayed on the page. This link will sort data by country, is there a way that I can replicate this but using a select list instead of text links.

```
<a ng-click="sort_by('country');">Country</a>
```

Part of my app.js

```
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 20 //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

So I'd like this to replicate the sort based on the selected value...

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="firstname">First name</option>
    <option value="lastname">Last name</option>
    <option value="company">Company name</option>
</select>
```

Comment: have you tried ng-change?

Comment: I tried ng-change='sort_by(value)' but if I'm honest I don't know how to pass the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to bind the dropdown into a value called `sortValue` of $scope

```
<select ng-model="sortValue" class="form-control">
   <option value="firstname">First name</option>
   <option value="lastname">Last name</option>
   <option value="company">Company name</option>
</select>
```

In the controller, set a watch to change the filter when the `sortValue` change:

```
$scope.$watch('sortValue',function(newValue, oldValue){
    //newValue here is the selected value
    $scope.sort_by(newValue);
});
```